# PyDrake PiecewisePolynomial.FirstOrderHold error

Tags: drake

I'm plugging in my own trajectory, x[t] and a list of breakpoints. But when I run it, I'm getting a runtime error:

Exception while evaluating SNOPT costs and constraints: 'Penetration queries between shapes 'Box' and 'Box' are not supported for scalar type drake::AutoDiffXd'

However, it works when I set the breakpoints to [0.0, 4.0] and the states to np.hstack([init_state, final_state]).

My states have some jitters, so I cut it down to once per second to try removing this. I also removed my input limits, so the DirectCollocation program has no constraints (but u still has a running cost and there is a final cost). Yet I still get the same issue.

What can I do to get around this/what should I be looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough to go on in your question for us to help.  I've inferred that you are (1) using DirectCollocation, and (2) are passing in a PiecewisePolynomial as the initial guess for the state trajectory.

I *suspect* that what is happening is that one of your initial guesses is causing the solver to explore trajectories which puts the state into contact, and the other is not.  When the state has box-on-box contact, then you run into this error.

To see the list of supported geometries for autodiff through contact, you can look at Table 2 [here](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_query_object.html#af3b16adde799eb804619dc86f3703f4f).